# JDBC Template querying

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jdbc

I am trying to execute this method using jdbc template:

```
 public String getClientName(String uuid) {
    System.out.println("UUID here in the dao layer is: " + uuid);
    String sql = "Select email from client where uuid=?";

    return jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new ResultSetExtractor<String>() {

        @Override
        public String extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException,        DataAccessException {
            return rs.getString("email");
        }
    });
}
```

However I am getting this error:

```
SQLErrorCodes loaded: [DB2, Derby, H2, HSQL, Informix, MS-SQL, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, Sybase, Hana]
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [Select email from client where uuid=?]; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying =?
Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not passing the uuid which you got as a parameter to your method. You could do use the [api](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object[],%20org.springframework.jdbc.core.ResultSetExtractor%29) like:

```
Object sqlParameters[] = {uuid};
return jdbcTemplate.query(sql, sqlParameters,
new ResultSetExtractor<List<String>>() {  
    @Override
    public List<String> extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
        List<String> emailList=new ArrayList<String>();  
        while (rs.next()) {
            emailList.add(rs.getString("email"));
        }
        return emailList;
    }});
```

Comment: Thanks,i have noticed that and corrected this however i get this error now "ResultSet not positioned properly"

Comment: That's perhaps because you get multiple email ids and you are not iterating over them. Try the updated code.

Comment: That seemed to do it.thanks man.i did not know i was getting 2 email addresses .i was under the assumption i was getting one.

Answer (score 2):

You're not using your `uuid` parameter anywhere... I suspect you actually want:

```
return jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new Object[] { uuid },
    new ResultSetExtractor<String>() { ... });
```

That way `uuid` will be used as the value for the parameter in your SQL.

Comment: Thanks that seemed to be it however i get another error after stating " ResultSet not positioned properly" .

Comment: Thanks Jon u have also helped me on this.yup i was not iterating through the resultset properly.